# TensorFlow: varscope.reuse_variables()

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

How do I reuse variables in TensorFlow? I want to reuse the `tf.contrib.layers.linear`

```
with tf.variable_scope("root") as varscope:
    inputs_1 = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[2, 3, 4])
    inputs_2 = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[2, 3, 4])
    outputs_1 = tf.contrib.layers.linear(inputs_1, 5)
    varscope.reuse_variables()
    outputs_2 = tf.contrib.layers.linear(inputs_2, 5)
```

But it gives me the following result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-a40b9ec68e25> in <module>()
      5     outputs_1 = tf.contrib.layers.linear(inputs_1, 5)
      6     varscope.reuse_variables()
----> 7     outputs_2 = tf.contrib.layers.linear(inputs_2, 5)
...
ValueError: Variable root/fully_connected_1/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is tf.contrib.layers.linear automatically creates a new set of linear layers with its own scope. When calling scope.reuse() there's nothing to be reused because those are new variables.

Try to do something like this instead

```
def function():
  with tf.variable_scope("root") as varscope:
    inputs = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[2, 3, 4])
    outputs = tf.contrib.layers.linear(inputs, 5)
    return outputs

result_1 = function()
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
result_2 = function()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
a = sess.run(result_1)
b = sess.run(result_2)
np.all(a == b) # ==> True
```

Comment: I copy pasted that piece of code. It doesn't work? same error as before.

Comment: Sorry you're right I had a bug previously reuse should be a function. I expanded it to show an example.

Comment: Cool, it works now! Now what exactly is the difference between your code and taking OPs code, but adding `scope=varscope` in both `layers.linear`? Thanks!

Comment: Well the issue isn't with scope but instead the issue is with the function layers.linear() .  So I did a bit of hunting down and it seems like linear() is an alias to https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#fully_connected so just pass in reuse=True if you done want to call resuse_variables.

Comment: The problem and difference come down to that in both cases you're calling this function .linear() which creates new variables everytime its called.  If instead you put it in as a function then it's only called once and instead I called reuse on the already existing variables telling tensorflow to reuse the previously created variables when I call on this function again.  Not sure if that makes sense or not but feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: So when defining it as a function the graph does not create a new node, but reuse the old one? What If I supply it with a different input of the same shape? such that `function(input)`?

Comment: function(input) will also work to reuse the old variables provided you have the same setup that I described.  One other thing you can try is passing in reuse=True like so .linear(inputs, 5, reuse=True) as an alternative to calling tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() in between calls.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to modify `linear(inputs_1, 5)` to `linear(inputs_1, 5, scope="linear")`

```
with tf.variable_scope("root") as varscope:
    inputs_1 = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[2, 3, 4])
    inputs_2 = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[2, 3, 4])
    outputs_1 = tf.contrib.layers.linear(inputs_1, 5, scope="linear")
    varscope.reuse_variables()
    outputs_2 = tf.contrib.layers.linear(inputs_2, 5, scope="linear")
```